# Recursion with palindromes

Tags: python, string, recursion, substring, palindrome

I have a recursion statement with python.

**STATEMENT**

**PALINDROMES**

> A palindrome is a word which reads the same backwards as forwards (madam, noon, radar…).
> Write a program which reads a string and prints all palindromes, which can be obtained by removing of some characters of the string. The resulting palindromes do not need to be English words!*

**Restrictions:**

- Do not print palindromes of the length 1 (one-letter palindromes).
- Each palindrome is printed exactly once.

I have written the following code that works perfectly, but in the second defined function I have not used recursion because I did not know how to approach this part of the statement.
If someone can help me I would be so thankful.

```
def find_subsets(seq, n):
    if n != 0:
        result = []
        subsets = find_subsets(seq, n-1)
        for subset in subsets:
            result += [subset]
            result += [[seq[n-1]] + subset]
        return result
    else:
        return [[]]
def check_palindrome(subsetsList):
    finalList = []
    for x in subsetsList:
        if x[::-1] == x and len(x)>1:
            string = " ".join(x)
            print(string)
        else:
           continue
word = input("Write string: ")
check_palindrome(find_subsets(word, len(word)))
```

Comment: Why does `check_palindrome` need to use recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement a recursive version of `check_palindrome` would be to replace your `for` loop with calls to `check_palindrome`.  To avoid an infinite loop, however, you would need remove a value from the list and process it, thereby shrinking `subsetsList` by 1 with each recursive call.  Lastly, you would need to check when `subsetsList` became empty and back out of the recursion at that point.

Example:

```
def check_palindrome(subsetsList):
    if not subsetsList:
        return
    
    x = subsetsList.pop()
    if x[::-1] == x and len(x)>1:
        string = " ".join(x)
        print(string)
    
    check_palindrome(subsetsList)
```